# Change the path for saving file using paperclip/rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, paperclip

I am making Rails app and using paperclip to upload files to AWS S3 bucket.
In my model, I configure like following way:

```
 class File < ApplicationRecord
    has_attached_file :attachment,
                                :url => "/sample_pdf/:basename.:extension",
                                :path => "/sample_pdf/:basename.:extension"

    validates_attachment :attachment,
                                         :content_type => {
                                                 :content_type =>
                                                         ["application/pdf"]
                                         }
end
```

The problem I am facing is that sometimes I need to upload the file to `"/sample_pdf/:basename.:extension"` and sometimes I need to upload to other path like following `"/another_pdf_folder/:basename.:extension"`.

I am not sure whether there's a way to change the path where I store the file depends on my needs.

Thanks.